# From a Catholic perspective, what do family relationships look like in heaven?

Tags: heaven, family, relationships

According to [Matthew 22:30](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+22%3A30&version=RSVCE), people in heaven do not marry. What do the family relationships look like there? Will our relations to parents, kids, wives and husbands disappear?

The Catholic position preferred and biblical arguments welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What is the beatitude of heaven?*

[Catechism of the Catholic Church 1027](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a12.htm#1027) answers:

> This mystery of blessed communion with God and all who are in Christ
>   is beyond all understanding and description. Scripture speaks of it in
>   images: life, light, peace, wedding feast, wine of the kingdom, the
>   Father's house, the heavenly Jerusalem, paradise: "no eye has seen,
>   nor ear heard, nor the heart of man conceived, what God has prepared
>   for those who love him."<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1. [1 Cor
>   2:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+2%3A9&version=RSVCE).</sup>

Thus it is the [blessed](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blessed) ( = supremely happy) 1) communion with God and 2) communion with all who are in Christ.

Catholic theology expands on this by calling the former "Essential beatitude" and the latter "Accidental beatitude". And part of the accidental beatitude is:

> They delight greatly in the company of Christ, the angels, and the
>   saints, and *in the reunion with so many who were dear to them on
>   earth*<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2. cf. *Accidental beatitude* in [Heaven | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/07170a.htm)</sup>

They way I see it, it will be coming home to one great big family reunion, wonderful and beyond all telling. cf. [Matt 8:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+8%3A11&version=RSVCE):

> 11 I tell you, many will come from east and west and sit at table with
>   Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob in the kingdom of heaven[.]